# Azure Search Service REST API Delete Error: "Document key cannot be missing or empty."

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cognitive-search

I am seeing some intermittent and odd behavior when trying to use the [Azure Search Service REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents) to delete a blob storage blob/document.  It works, sometimes, and then other times I get this:

> The request is invalid. Details: actions : 0: Document key cannot be
>   missing or empty.

[image]

Once I start getting this error, it's the same results when I try to delete any of the document/blobs stored in that index.  I do have 'metadata_storage_path' listed as my index key (see below).
I have not been able to get the query to succeed again, or I would examine the differences in Fiddler.

[image]

I have also tried the following with no luck:

1. Resetting and re-running the associated search indexer.
2. Creating a new indexer & index against the same container and deleting from that.
3. Creating a new container, indexer, & index and deleting from that.

Any additional suggestions or thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste error:  "metadata_storage_name" should be "metadata_storage_path".

[Insert head-banging-on-wall emoji here.]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Are you still experiencing those issues? If yes, can you email me the name of your service so I can investigate the logs? my email is my user name (without the -MSFT) at microsoft dot com. thanks

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still searching for the solution...

Instead of id,

```
{  
  "value": [  
    {  
      "@search.action": "delete",
      "id":"TDVRT0FPQXcxZGtTQUFBQUFBQUFBQT090fdf"
    } 
  ]  
}
```

Use rid of your document to delete.

```
{  
  "value": [  
    {  
      "@search.action": "delete",
      "rid":"TDVRT0FPQXcxZGtTQUFBQUFBQUFBQT090fdf"
    } 
  ]  
}
```

Because while creating Search Index, you might have selected rid as your unique id column.

**Note:** We can delete a document only with Unique Id Columns.